# SQLite Database does not update record with PUT- returns a 302 redirect rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

In my project, I try to update a record, so once I click "update" I am redirected to the previous page, as if the record was updated since the parameters are passed through. However, instead of updating, the porduction.log show a return of a 302 redirect, but with no accessing a database to change the values in the paramters.

Controller:

```
def show
@hour = HourLog.find(params[:id])
@status = @hour.status
  end
def update
@hour = HourLog.find(params[:id])
if @hour.update(update_hour_params)
  redirect_to '/hours'
else
  redirect_to "/hours/#{id}"
end
end
```

View(show.html.erb):

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <%= form_for(@hour, url: hour_path, method: :patch) do |f| %>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr id="dashtexttable">
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Assignment</th>
        <th>Hours</th>
        <th>Supervisor/Location</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      </thead>

          <tbody>
          <tr id="dashfield">
            <td><%= @hour.user.first_name + ' ' + @hour.user.last_name  %></td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :assignment, :value => @hour.assignment %></td>
            <td><%= f.number_field :hours, in: 0.5..12.0, step: 0.5, :value => @hour.hours %></td>
            <td> <%= f.text_field :supervisor, :value => @hour.supervisor %></td>
            <td><%= f.date_field :date, :value => @hour.date %></td>
            <td><%= f.hidden_field :status, :value => 'Confirmed'%>
              <%= f.submit 'Update'%></td>

    <%end %>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', hour_path(@hour), method: :delete %></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Routes:

```
root 'welcome#index'
get '/signup' => 'users#new'
resources :users
get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
delete '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
post '/hours/new' => 'hours#create'
resources :hours
get '/leaderboard' => 'leaderboard#index'
get '/essay' => 'essay#index'
resources :essay
```

Model

```
class HourLog < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end
```

Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: Provide your model. The update is probably failing and redirecting to "/hours/#{id}" since something is not valid on your update (your model class).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `update_attributes` like this:

```
@hour.update_attributes(update_hour_params)
```

Here is a reference of the difference between these methods:

[Difference between active record methods – update, update_all, update_attribute, update_attributes](https://priyankapathak.wordpress.com/2010/08/21/difference-between-active-record-methods-update-update_all-update_attribute-update_attributes/)

Comment: Thank you for the response! The method I was using worked for development mode, but is not working in production mode, and I tried to use your update but that failed in development mode because it said update_hour_params was not a define method

Comment: I also just checked with update_attributes in the controller and it makes no difference

Comment: Could there be a problem with the database? It has not given me problems up until now.